# How to make the Wrap widget child inside SingleChildScrollView to expand to full height in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a UI where there are some text fields inside a container and there are some icon buttons which are always going to stay at the bottom.

Here is the code minimal code

```
Center(
  child: Container(
    // width: 1006,
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxWidth: 1006,
      maxHeight: sizingInformation.screenSize.height,
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
      left: isMobile ? 0 : 34,
    ),
    child: Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      Flex(
      // rest of the widgets
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(isMobile ? 15 : 34),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: isMobile ? 15 : 27,
          ),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: 1006,
          ),
          height: 750,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: CARD_DARK_PURPLE,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            child: Wrap(
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                Wrap(
                  direction: Axis.horizontal,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Pošiljalac",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: WHITE,
                            fontSize: isMobileTablet ? 22 : 24,
                            fontWeight: BOLD,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        _phoneInfo(widget.order.senderPhoneNumber, isMobile),
                        _emailInfo(widget.order.senderEmail, isMobile),
                        _fullNameInfo(widget.order.senderFirstName,
                            widget.order.senderLastName, isMobile, isMobileTablet),
                        _addressInfo(widget.order.senderStreetNumber, isMobile),
                        _zipCodeInfo(widget.order.senderZipCode, isMobile),
                        _cityInfo(widget.order.senderCity, isMobile),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: isDesktopLaptop ? 14 : 0,
                        ),
                        _payeeInfo(isMobile,  isMobileTablet),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 34,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: isDesktopLaptop ? 482 : 10,
                        ),
                        _weightInfo(isMobile,  isMobileTablet),
                        _noteSmall(isMobile,  isMobileTablet),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Flex(
                        direction: Axis.horizontal,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(width: 20),
                          Material(
                            color: DIVIDER,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Ink(
                                decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                                  color: DIVIDER,
                                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                                ),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  splashColor: DARK_PURPLE.withOpacity(0.3),
                                  icon: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/inter-note-icon.png',
                                    width: 20,
                                    height: 24,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    if (widget.order.operatorNote == "/") {
                                      _dialogs.internNoteDialog(
                                          context,
                                          widget.order.id,
                                          "order",
                                          widget.order.operatorNote);
                                    } else {
                                      _dialogs.changeInternNoteDialog(
                                          context,
                                          widget.order.id,
                                          "order",
                                          widget.order.operatorNote);
                                    }
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 20),
                          Material(
                            color: DIVIDER,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                            ),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Ink(
                                decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                                  color: DIVIDER,
                                  shape: CircleBorder(),
                                ),
                                child: IconButton(
                                  splashColor: DARK_PURPLE.withOpacity(0.3),
                                  icon: Image.asset(
                                    'assets/images/trash-icon.png',
                                    width: 28,
                                    height: 28,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _dialogs.deleteOrderDialog(
                                        context, widget.order.id, isMobile);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),  
    ),
  ),
)
```

This is the UI that I'm trying to achieve(the box highlighted on the right side specifically)
[image]

There is `SingleChildScrollView` parent which has Wrap as its child. `SingleChildScrollView` is taking the full height available but `Wrap` isn't spanning to that full height. I want to make the `Wrap` span full height so that the icons can stay at the bottom always.

So, I placed it inside `Expanded` as I thought it would make it expand to the full available height. But I got this error.

```
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a _SingleChildViewport widget.

The ownership chain for the RenderObject that received the incompatible parent data was:
  Wrap ← Expanded ← _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#01401] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#7427b] ← _PointerListener ← ⋯
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
dart:sdk_internal 4461:11                                                 throw_
packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js 12339:23             <fn>
packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js 12355:24             [_updateParentData]
packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js 12372:61             attachRenderObject
packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js 12184:12             mount
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

So, Expanded is not the answer to this. But I don't know what else is. I'm new to Flutter and having a hard time understanding the Flutter layout system. Any help would be great. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not sure about the layout you try to achieve but if the buttons should always be at the button of the screen i feel like they should not be inside the SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: @ZeRj By staying at bottom means they'll come after the text fields at the bottom if there is a scroll and if there isn't a scroll then stay in the bottom.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've got the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

What if you make your `Wrap` widget the child of a container the size of the screen ?

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Wrap(
                children: [],
              ))),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. But this wouldn't work in my case as the height isn't going to be the height of the viewport. There are other widgets as well so can't do this.

Comment: @Bhawna then you need to update your OP with the widget tree you have along with a screenshot for a clearer understanding

Comment: I've added the widget tree and screenshot of UI. Hope that helps.